# Django How to send request to views.py using javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Hello
Can any one tell me how to send request to a function in views.py in Django? Thanks

Comment: Just make an AJAX request to the URL - what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a neat post called [AJAX in Django with jQuery](http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/)

Answer (score 0):

If don't know how to call a function, you should start out by reading http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how to connect a view to a url ?" then I advise you to go through [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)... very fast, very clear !

Comment: of Course, I won't ask low level questions. Django Tutoiral I have gone through thousands of times. Send request to views.py from javascript

Comment: You don't tell in your question that is should be sent from javascript. Then, see other people's answers